# How to convert code from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I wrote this code in SQL Server. I want to write this code for Oracle and PL/SQL. Could anyone help me how I can do this job?

SQL Server / T-SQL:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[checkBalance]
   ON  [dbo].[Orders]
FOR insert
AS
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT goodcount FROM goods WHERE id=(SELECT gid FROM Inserted)) < (SELECT gcount FROM Inserted)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Inventory is low',10,1)
        rollback
    END
```

Comment: You need to take a stab at it first, and post what you've tried.  No one is going to write it for you without seeing what effort you put in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MySchema.checkBalance
AFTER INSERT 
    ON MySchema.Orders FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    v_count pls_integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT goodcount INTO v_count FROM goods WHERE id = :new.gid;
    If v_count < :new.gcount Then
        raise_application_error (-20001,'Low inventory.');
    End If;
END;
```

Comment: tnx, but, this code send error! ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers

Comment: Ok, i added this code, but get error! Error at line 3: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FOR" when expecting one of the